# Measurability of $\|f(\cdot)\|$, if $f$ is weak measurable

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove Pettis Measurability Theorem and it seems that I 'm making a mistake.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Let $X$ be a normed space, $X^*$ its dual of linear, bounded functionals and $f: \Omega \to X$. We assume that $f$ is weak mesurable, e.g. $w \mapsto x^*(f(w))$ is measurable for all $x^* \in X^*$. Further we assume that $f$ is essentially separably valued, e.g. there is a $\mu$-null set $E$ such that $f(\Omega \setminus E)$ is separable.

We need to prove that $w \mapsto \|f(w)\|$ is measurable.
I already proved, that the closed unit dual ball $\overline{B}_1^{X^*}$ is sequentially compact w.r.t. the w*-topology.
I would use the following:

> **Corollary of Hahn-Banach**:
> In every normed Space $X$ there holds:
> $$\|x\| = \sup_{x^* \in \overline{B}_1^{X^*}} | x^*(x) |.$$

So one can write
$$\|f(w)\| = \sup_{x^* \in \overline{B}_1^{X^*}} | x^*(f(w)) |,$$
but this does not have to be measurable. One can chose a maximizing sequence $\{x_n^*\} \subseteq \overline{B}_1^{X^*}$ which contains a w*-convergent subsequence such that

$$\sup_{x^* \in \overline{B}_1^{X^*}} |x^*(f(w))| =
\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |x_{n_k}^*(f(w))|.$$
So this would be measurable. Is this the correct way?

Comment: That's wrong because $x^*$ depends on $w$, so $||f(w)||=x^*(f(w))$ should be $||f(w)||=x^*(w)(f(w))$, no longer what comes up in the definition.

Comment: Ah ok I missed that point. Is there an example where one can see, that it is not measurable anymore?

Comment: It can be hard coming up with a counterexample for an incorrect proof of a true fact...

Comment: ok thanks. I changed the question a bit to use another Hahn-Banach corollary. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: I must be missing something - looks to me like exactly the same problem as before. That minimizing sequence depends on $w$.

Comment: No you are not, I'm sorry. I found a theorem which states that if $F \subseteq X$ is a separable subset and $Y \subseteq X^*$ is a norming
subset for F, then Y contains a sequence which is norming for F. But the proof doesn't involve w*-sequentially compactness. I'll talk to my prof and update the question asap I clearly understood the problem. thanks a lot @DavidC.Ullrich